# Creating a frame using structures

Tags: c, data-structures, embedded-linux, microcontroller, ram

I am seeking for an advice for creating a frame of unsigned char
values using a structure which is to be used in an Embedded system
application which is having less RAM.

Eg. I am having 10 bytes RAM(say). Need to create a frame(frame1)
within the RAM memory dynamically using structures in c and print
it and then free it. Then create (frame2), print and then free it
within the same 10 bytes of RAM memory. This is an interview
question for me.

My answer:

```
  struct frame1 /*  first frame */
  {
     unsigned char value1; /* Structure members*/
     unsigned char value2;
     unsigned char value3;
     unsigned char value4;
     /* created upto 10 values (say value10)*/
  }*p;  

  p = (struct frame1*)malloc(sizeof(struct frame1)); /* dynamically
  allocating memory for frame1 */

  p->value1 = 0x10; /* Assigning values to the members  */
  p->value2 = 0x20; 
  p->value3 = 0x30;
  p->value4 = 0x40; 
  /* Given upto 10 values */

  /*print it*/
  free(p);

  /* Then created another structure for frame2 done the same as above
  and freed it */
```

I am not sure what the interviewer expected from me. But I have 
written based on the suggestions he gave.

The Interviewer said like it's ok to do like this in one angle. But 
it looks like very basic level of code in terms of structure. So he
need to do it in advanced level. Kindly help me how to handle this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a c code for the requirement mentioned above since I have given a sample code what I thought. Maybe this is not the best practice code. Please support.

Comment: Just do it using loops, it's better